# Why manipulated netCDF file in R environment produces rasters with a different resolution compared to the ones created in ArcGIS?

Tags: r, arrays, gis, netcdf4

I'm dealing with a netcdf4 file downloaded from the Marine Environment Monitoring Service of Copernicus and I think I miss something here...

Consider my approach in the following code to extract values from the nc file. My scope is to reanalyze the data stored in the time series with a linear regression in order to get the mean SST change per day per pixel (not quite sure if I'm getting the statistic I want here! I'm open to suggestions! anyway this is not the point of my thread).

```
library(ncdf4)
library(raster)
nc_data <- nc_open('L4_analyzed_sst_005res_25081981_31122018.nc')
print(nc_data) #it shows metadata

lon <- ncvar_get(nc_data, "lon")
lat <- ncvar_get(nc_data, "lat", verbose = F)
t <- ncvar_get(nc_data, "time")
t1 <- as.POSIXct(t, origin="1981-01-01", format="%Y-%m-%d", tz = "UTC")

sst.array <- ncvar_get(nc_data, "analysed_sst") # store the data in a 3-dimensional array (long, lat, time)
dim(sst.array)

fillvalue <- ncatt_get(nc_data, "analysed_sst", "_FillValue")
fillvalue
nc_close(nc_data)

sst.array[sst.array == fillvalue$value] <- NA #fill the no value with NA

str(sst.array)

##################################################################################################
#1. sst change for the entire period
#######################################################################################
slope_matrix <- matrix(nrow = length(lon), ncol = length(lat))
for (i in 1:dim(sst.array)[1]){
  for (j in 1:dim(sst.array)[2]){
    value <- sst.array[i,j,]
    if (anyNA(value)==FALSE){ #this "if" speed up the process because in my case the only NA are noValue
    extracted_data <- data.frame(value=value, t=t1)
    extracted_data$quarter <- "null"
    extracted_data$quarter <- ifelse(substr(extracted_data$t, 6,7)=="01"|substr(extracted_data$t, 6,7)=="02"|substr(extracted_data$t, 6,7)=="03", "Q1", extracted_data$quarter)
    extracted_data$quarter <- ifelse(substr(extracted_data$t, 6,7)=="04"|substr(extracted_data$t, 6,7)=="05"|substr(extracted_data$t, 6,7)=="06", "Q2", extracted_data$quarter)
    extracted_data$quarter <- ifelse(substr(extracted_data$t, 6,7)=="07"|substr(extracted_data$t, 6,7)=="08"|substr(extracted_data$t, 6,7)=="09", "Q3", extracted_data$quarter)
    extracted_data$quarter <- ifelse(substr(extracted_data$t, 6,7)=="10"|substr(extracted_data$t, 6,7)=="11"|substr(extracted_data$t, 6,7)=="12", "Q4", extracted_data$quarter)
    model <- lm(value ~ time(t) + quarter, data = extracted_data)
    slope_matrix[i,j] <- mean(predict(model) - extracted_data$value)
    }
  }
}

slope_raster <- raster(t(slope_matrix), xmn=min(lon), xmx=max(lon), ymn=min(lat), ymx=max(lat), crs=CRS("+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs+ towgs84=0,0,0"))
plot(slope_raster)
slope_raster <- flip(slope_raster, direction='y')
writeRaster(slope_raster, "sst_change_1981-2018.tif", "GTiff", overwrite=TRUE)
```

I used the nc file as an array and built a nested for loop in order to model the time series in each pixel. Then, I transformed the matrix of values into a raster, flip it to reorient it, and wrote it as a GeoTIFF for further uses.
Now, when I open it in ArcGIS, it does not perfectly overlap with the raster created with the "make netCDF raster layer" tool. The raster created in R has slightly a smaller resolution (0.049 vs 0.050).

Do you know what's the problem here?

Thank you for the help!

**EDIT**: [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1l9zR6I12kV-ncZVex-4DPoEGK6BmOgxQ/view?usp=sharing) you can download the data.

Comment: can you please rewrite your question to focus at the issue at hand. This appears to be the correct resolution. If so most of what you show is irrelevant, but you do not show much that can help answer your question, So how can we know. Can you make the file available? Can you show `raster::brick("file.nc")`?

Comment: Hi Robert. I just wanted to show how I created my raster. If the process is correct, then I'd like to know why R and ArcGIS produce rasters with different resolutions, that's it. I added the link for the data in the question.

Comment: Can you show what you get with `brick("file.nc")` and what you get with your method ---- so that we can compare (and remove the irrelevant bits)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are *much* easier ways to deal with ncdf files with spatial data. Below I open the file with the `raster` package (that has R based code for this) and with the `terra` package (that uses the GDAL library).  They give the same resolution; so it safe to assume that this is correct.

```
f <- "L4_analyzed_sst_005res_25081981_31122018.nc"
library(raster)
b <- brick(f)
b
#class      : RasterBrick 
#dimensions : 34, 48, 1632, 13643  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
#resolution : 0.05004599, 0.05015772  (x, y)
#extent     : 13.22879, 15.631, 39.52957, 41.23494  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#crs        : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 
#source     : L4_analyzed_sst_005res_25081981_31122018.nc 
#names      : X1981.08.25, X1981.08.26, X1981.08.27, X1981.08.28, X1981.08.29, X1981.08.30, X1981.08.31, X1981.09.01, X1981.09.02, X1981.09.03, X1981.09.04, X1981.09.05, X1981.09.06, X1981.09.07, X1981.09.08, ... 
#Date/time  : 1981-08-25, 2018-12-31 (min, max)
#varname    : analysed_sst
```

Or with `terra`

```
x <- rast(f)
x
#class       : SpatRaster 
#dimensions  : 34, 48, 13643  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#resolution  : 0.05004599, 0.05015772  (x, y)
#extent      : 13.22879, 15.631, 39.52957, 41.23494  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 
#data source : L4_analyzed_sst_005res_25081981_31122018.nc 
#names       : L4__1, L4__2, L4__3, L4__4, L4__5, L4__6, ...
```

The resolution that you use is wrong because you do:

```
raster(nrow=34, ncol=48, xmn=min(lon), xmx=max(lon), ymn=min(lat), ymx=max(lat))
#class      : RasterLayer 
#dimensions : 34, 48, 1632  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
#resolution : 0.04900336, 0.04868249  (x, y)
#extent     : 13.25381, 15.60598, 39.55465, 41.20986  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#crs        : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs
```

You are using the lon/lat values of the centers of the corner cells. But what you need to supply are the coordinates of the outer edge of the corner cells.

Unrelated to your question, but you could now go on and compute the quarters (outside any loop --- no need to do it again and again for each cell?)

```
z <- getZ(b)
month <- as.numeric(substr(z, 6 ,7 ))
quarter <- ((month-1) %% 4 ) + 1
# or quarter <- trunc((month-1) / 3) + 1
table(quarter)
#quarter
#   1    2    3    4 
#3434 3333 3435 3441
```

And see `?calc` for examples of doing cell-based regression

Comment: Suppose I'd use the `brick` command to access the nc file, how could I achieve the goal of performing a regression analysis over `nlayers(b)` for each `ncell(b)` and wrote it as GeoTIFF ?

Comment: see `?calc` for examples of doing cell-based regression --- but you can also keep the regression code you have, and get the values with something like `values(b)` and then set the values with `setValues(raster(b), slope)`

Comment: Thank you very much Robert! I fixed everything with `values` and `setValues`!!